# Not able to render image ever second via AJAX call .Net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, signalr

I am developing a web application using ASP .Net core. As a part of the requirement, I have to render an Image every second on the webpage (The image path is coming from the DB).

Currently, I am using AJAX call and set it up in Setinterval Method (I have set it at .400 seconds for testing). I am noticing that the performance is not optimal - 1 image is being rendered in 3 seconds. Is there a better alternative to Ajax in this scenario?

I mean any better solution - A machine vision system is storing images from the camera in a local drive and paths of these images are been stored in the table. I need to fetch the data (in my case image path) as soon as it is available in the table and display it on a near real-time basis. I tried this with AJAX but couldn't achieve it.

I was reading about Signal-R or Blazor with Signal-r to display data (in my case its new Images) on a real-time basis but it would nice if I get experts advice before jumping into anything new.

Thank you in advance for your help!

below is my code:

Controller :

```
  string image = null;
                if (db.Images.Any())
                {
                    image = db.Images.ToList().OrderByDescending(e => e.ImageId).FirstOrDefault().ImagePath;
                    return Ok(image);
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
```

View/AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/ImagesRetrieve/GetImages1",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#dvImage").attr("src", "/images" + data);
                        $("#btnColour").css("background-color","#4CAF50");

  }
                });
 }, 400);
```

Comment: this makes me confused `render an Image every second on the webpage`? So you have just one same image (not changed) and why do we have to render it every second? Isn't showing it just one time enough? If you mean you have multiple images and each one should be rendered sequentially after each second, then it really depends how many images you have so that you can pick several different solutions. The general solution is to ensure the next image ready before being shown. So that means yo have to somehow preload several images (in background) first, queue them all and dequeue each for rendering.

Comment: It's not the same image. Machine Vision system is capturing the images of an object every second and stores them on the local repository (also adding their paths to the DB table). I need to display them as soon as the latest image is available in the table (I mean it's like showing them near real-time basis on the web-page).

Comment: so there is always a minimum delay between the time your image is updated and the time it's shown/rendered. That delay is equal to the time you load the image from the server to the client. So actually it's not in real time. By increasing that delay you can increase the reliability of showing the latest image (to ensure that each second a new one is shown). You need a queue on the client, each second send a loading request to get the latest image (the server should ensure to avoid dup images returned), push all to the queue, each second dequeue it and render normally.

Comment: Thanks for your instant response but is there a way I can display the images as soon as there are available in the table?  This is my assumption that the Image path will be stored every 1 second. It could be less than a second or most of the time it's more than a second.

Comment: Your issue is just a problem of the so-called `producer-consumer`. It applies the separation of concerns principle. The producer & consumer concerns. The consumer (client) works well as long as the queue always has item, it just picks item from there. The producer should be fast enough to ensure the items pushed into the queue for the consumer. So increasing the delay (as I mentioned above) can give the producer more time to load more items into the queue, so you have a more reliable queue (always containing some item) for the consumer to work correctly (get & render 1 image each second).

Comment: if you have some event on the server side for the time the new image is updated, you can use `SignalR` to push back that image to the client and store it into the queue (on the client side). That's fairly simple. Try reading more about the producer-consumer pattern, there are examples out there as well.

Comment: OK, I will look at them.